# How to properly refactor code fetching data from db (EF Core)?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I wrote a code which uses LINQ to fetch data from db and save it to a list. I added an interface which I implement in `ClientsRepository`. And this the class where I need to refactor my code. My code is shown below:

```
    public class Clients
    {
        public Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IClientsRepository
    {
        Task<List<Clients>> ListAllClients();
    }

    public class ClientsRepository : IClientsRepository
    {
        private List<Clients> _clientsList;


        public ClientsRepository(MainDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
        {
        }

        public async Task<List<Clients>> ListAllClients()
        {
            _clientsList = new List<Clients>();

            var query = await _dbContext.ClientsTbl
                                .AsQueryable()
                                .AsNoTracking()
                                .Join(_dbContext.AddressTbl.AsNoTracking(),
                                client => client.Id,
                                address => address.ClientId,
                                (client, address) => new
                                {
                                    client.Id,
                                    client.Name,
                                    address.FullAddress
                                })
                                .ToListAsync();

            var allClients = query
                            .Select(s => new Clients 
                            { 
                                Id = s.Id,
                                Name= s.Name,
                                Address = s.FullAddress
                            });
            
            return _clientsList;
        }
    }
}
```

1. I would like to use `IQueryable` to enumerate through db tables which seems more efficient than `IEnumerable`. The issue is that I don't know how to join tables when `IQueryable` is used, I think `Join` method doesn't seem to be working with `IQueryable`. I also tried to make my interface's method as `IQueryable`, I mean `Task<IQueryable<Clients>> ListAllClients()` but after that I got error message to cast my List to `IQueryable`, namely to do so: `return (IQueryable<Clients>) _clientsList;`. It doesn't look good.
2. I would like to build the expression tree without executing on the collection. I build my LINQ query in `query` variable. At the end of it there's `.ToListAsync()` method which forces the query to execute. I don't want that here. I wanted to return all data in `var allClients` as a seperate code. That's why I added `.AsQueryable()` to my query LINQ code to store data in-memory. Unfortunately, there is an error: `'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable'`
3. Not sure if code responsible for populating list of clients (in `var allClients=..`) could also be  be refactored?

Comment: If you want to return `IQueryable`, method should be not async. Async is needed only when you materialise objects via `ToListAsync`, for example. So just return IQueryable. And no, `Join` works with `IQueryable`.

Comment: Ok, so I'm wondering now if I need `IQueryable` at all. As far as I know it's a good practice to use this interface to fetch data from db, it's more efficient. That's why I wanted to use it in my code. I'm also wondering if I should force query to execute by using `.ToListAcync()`. I wanted to build sql statement (as `IQueryable`) and after that execute it in different chunk of code (in `allClients`). SO generally speaking I would like to somehow refactor my code since I guess it could be written in a better manner. I would need some advice

Comment: IMHO, my advice is simple, do not use Repository pattern with EF, DbContext it is already multi entities repository. Instead of it, create Extension methods over IQueryable which returns IQueryable, combine IQueryables and only at the end in controller/service call `ToListAsync`.

Comment: I try to imagine how it should look like but it's not easy for me. Anyways, thanks for support.

Comment: Some quick tips: remove these useless `Tbl` suffixes; don't join, use a navigation property `Client.Addresses`, project to a `ClientDto` class, not `Client` (because you don't return complete client objects); only return the `IQueryable`, not async; don't use repository; this method is more like a service method, not a typical repository method; let the consumer of this method actually execute the query, which may be done async.